# Create automatically list in a nested dictionary python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm extracting from a large dataframe the lists with the labels and the values, i'm storing them into a two separate lists, for example:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'], [114.98, 17.4, 21.1, 7.99, 51.5, 3000.0, 7.99, 68.5, 19.99]]
```

after i want to store inside every month this list of labels and values, and after i want to store all the 12 months (into the code i use the numbers from 1 to 12) into a dictionay of the years

I would like to create a dictionary formatted in this way:

```
{
2018.0: {1: [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'], [114.98, 17.4, 21.1, 7.99, 51.5, 3000.0, 7.99, 68.5, 19.99]], 2: [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'], [114.98, 17.4, 21.1, 7.99, 51.5, 3000.0, 7.99, 68.5, 19.99]], 3: [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'], [114.98, 17.4, 21.1, 7.99, 51.5, 3000.0, 7.99, 68.5, 19.99]], 4: [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'], [114.98, 17.4, 21.1, 7.99, 51.5, 3000.0, 7.99, 68.5, 19.99]],
2019.0: {1: [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'], [114.98, 17.4, 21.1, 7.99, 51.5, 3000.0, 7.99, 68.5, 19.99]], 2: [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'], [114.98, 17.4, 21.1, 7.99, 51.5, 3000.0, 7.99, 68.5, 19.99]], 3: [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'], [114.98, 17.4, 21.1, 7.99, 51.5, 3000.0, 7.99, 68.5, 19.99]], 4: [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'], [114.98, 17.4, 21.1, 7.99, 51.5, 3000.0, 7.99, 68.5, 19.99]]
...
}
```

The problem with my code is that it store the same labels and values of all the months in all the years. As you can see from a piece of the code, i've censored only the labels, but in the code the labels and the values for all the months are equal, and is not correct.
I know that is a little bit confusing. If something is not well explained let me know.

I've tried this:
the `a` variable is from another For cycle that iterate the years, and the `m` is for the

```
dma=dict.fromkeys(list_years) #how it looks dma {2018.0: None, 2019.0: None, 2020.0: None, 2021.0: None, 2022.0: None}
med=dict.fromkeys(list_months) #how it looks med {1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None, 5: None, 6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None, 11: None, 12: None}

for argomento in lista_cat_pulita:
            new_df = df.loc[(df["tipo"]=="Expense") & (df["mese"]==m) & (df["anno"]==a) & (df["categoria"]==argomento), "somma"].sum()

        label.append(argomento)
                value.append(new_df)

insieme.append(label)
insieme.append(value)

for ke, ve in dma.items():
    if ke == a:
        dma[ke]= med
        for ki, vi in med.items():
            if ki == m:
                med[ki] = insieme
```

**Edit**

```
years = ['2001.0', '2002.0', '2003.0']
months={1:None, 2:None, 3:None, 4:None, 5:None, 6:None, 7:None, 8:None, 9:None, 10:None, 11:None, 12:None}
dyears=dict.fromkeys(years)

for k, v in dyears.items():
    dyears[k]=months


for anno in years:
#other code

    for mese in range(1,13):
    #other code
    
        for argomento in lista_cat_pulita:
        
             new_df = df.loc[(df["tipo"]=="Expense") & (df["mese"]==m) & (df["anno"]==a) & (df["categoria"]==argomento), "somma"].sum()
              mesecategorielabel.append(argomento)
              meseValue.append(new_df)
        
        insieme.append(mesecategorielabel)
        insieme.append(meseValue)
        
    for ki, vi in dyears.items():
        if ki == anno:
        for sub_k, sub_v in vi.items():
            if sub_k == mese:
            dyears[ki][sub_k]=insieme

print(dyears)
```

The problem is that for every months i've a different list, but i do not know why all the months of the years are overwritten with the last 12 lists of the last year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create a dictionary of dictionaries. Use:

```
ml = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'], [114.98, 17.4, 21.1, 7.99, 51.5, 3000.0, 7.99, 68.5, 19.99]]

years = ['2001.0', '2002.0']

main_dict = {}
for year in years:
    main_dict[year] =  {i: ml for i in range(1,5)}

print(main_dict)
```

Comment: i'm trying to implementing it into my code, could you please explain me this little piece of code `i: ml for i`

Comment: Sure. `i in range(1,5)` produces the integers 1, 2, 3, 4 as you have described you want. The { } is a Dictionary comprehension which uses `i: ml` to produce a dictionary with a keys of i (1 to 4) and values of the same repeated List ml (which is a List of Lists) for each value of i.  This dictionary is then added to main_dict with a key of year taken from the years List. The process is repeated for each year. This produces the dictionary you show in your question. Happy to respond to any further questions.

Comment: thanks, i've tried to implement it but it overwrite like mine the previous lists, i'll add a piece of more code in the question. Because for every months i've a different list, but i do not know why all the months of the years are overwritten with the last 12 lists of the last year.

Comment: I don't really understand the last loop and why you can't simply use `dyears[anno][messe]=insieme` . When dictionary items are over-written that is because the key used is the same. What I would do is use several print calls to show exactly all variables and so see what is being used at every stage of the loop.

Comment: Thank you @user19077881 at the end i've opted for your solution that is cleaner